# Writing a utility to perform a simple action on a remote server

Tags: python, remote-server, utility

I need your advice on how to go about the following:

1. I am running a Counter Strike Game server on an Azure VM
2. The server is nothing but a Desktop utility that runs a service on certain port
   to which my friends connect and play the game
3. At times, I have to change the "map" on the game which means I have to go/login on the
   Azure VM and manually perform some actions (very basic like increase
   round-time for a match) or kick a user
4. Every time, I have to login on server and do this manually. If I want someone else to do it, then I
   will have to give them the VM access which is not what I want
5. I know moderate Python, so I can write a script that would actually perform
   this action (using Python OS library)
6. But I want to be able to run this script remotely from a web app or any other trigger

So the use case would look like this:

- A user goes to a URL (myGameserver.com:8989)
- He sees a list of available users in the game. He selects one and presses KICK button
- The kick button kicks that user from server by running a program that I mentioned in point 5 above
- The thing I need your help with is; What type of app /tech should I use to make this web application and How do I pass this "user selection" as an input to my program so that it knows what user to kick ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple flask api to kick players by steamid using rcon.

You can use curl to post data to it like this:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --d '{"steamid":"STEAM_1:0:1234567"}' \
  https://myGameserver.com:8989/kickplayer
```

The api:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import valve.rcon

app = Flask(__name__)

HOST = "0.0.0.0"
PORT = 8989
DEBUG = True

# replace with your VM's local ip if you are running this web app on the same VM as the csgo server
# or with the azure public ip if not. (You will need to open up port 27015 TCP for rcon)
CSGO_SERVER_IP = "10.0.100.100"
RCON_PORT = 27015
RCON_PASS = "supersekret123456"

@app.route('/kickplayer', methods=['POST'])
def kick_player():
    data = request.get_json()
    steamid = data["steamid"] # STEAM_1:0:XXXXXXXXX

    rcon_command = "sm_kick " + steamid

    with valve.rcon.RCON((CSGO_SERVER_IP, RCON_PORT), RCON_PASS) as rcon:
        response = rcon.execute(rcon_command)

    return f"Kicked player {steamid}"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=DEBUG, host=HOST, port=PORT)
```

Feel free to message me on discord for more advice, I run csgo servers and have written csgo web panels before: BurningTimes#1938

Comment: Brilliant dude! I will test that and will let you know. Thanks a lot